# Download a package with its all dependencies for later offline use

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dependencies

I would like to download package with its all dependencies to my computer and when I need it I would run command `dpkg -i *.deb`. All I need is to download everything necessary to install, say `vlc` or `g++` or `ubuntu-restricted-extras`. Please help. Thanks in advance.

P.S. I am sure it is a duplicate but I could not understand anything from other blogs.

Comment: Please check the answers on this duplicate question: [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Comment: LOL, this was the one I mentioned in postscript :) anyway thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want to install these packages on your local machine or on another one? If its the local machine you *could* use the `--download-only` switch of `apt-get`. Take a look at the [apt-get manpages](http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get).

That way the packages will be saved on the apt-cache that is usually located under `/var/cache/apt/archives`.

Also, I found the following on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419268/how-do-i-download-a-package-from-apt-get-without-installing-it):

`mkdir -p /tmp/archives/partial && apt-get -d -o dir::cache=/tmp -o Debug::NoLocking=1`

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for _good luck_ and for your answer :) but I think I need to reinstall my Ubuntu, because I have been playing with `-apt-get` and I started getting `unmet dependency` errors. :( But I am always happy for learning something new about Ubuntu and thanks for making me happy too :D